# how to setup a callback using react/flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm currently learning react/flux/alt. I have a Page with the following componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  LeaderBoardStore.listen(this.onChange);
  LeaderBoardActions.getCurrentWeek();
  LeaderBoardActions.getSeason();
  LeaderBoardActions.updateSortWeek(this.state.currentWeek);    
  LeaderBoardActions.getLeaders(this.query());
}
```

The problem I'm having is all of the actions are asynchronous. That is they call an api that doesn't respond until the callback is fired. This is in the Actions.

The question I have is how do I get the current week using the Actions and wait for it to process before I updateSortWeek()

Comment: What does `getCurrentWeek()` look like? You should probably use `promises` for this.

Comment: getCurrentWeek() {
      this.dispatch();
      api.get('/week', (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          this.actions.updateCurrentWeek('');
        } else {
          this.actions.updateCurrentWeek(res.body.week);
        }
      });
  }

Comment: Ok, so in the callback of `api.get` is where you want to call `updateSortWeek()`

Answer (score 2):

You should use promises inside the action creator and dispatch an action only after you get back the data from API call.

Example

```
getCurrentWeek: function() {
  // Make the API Call and get back the response (data)
  ApiUtils.getWeek().then(function(data){
  // Dispatch an action
  AppDispatcher.dispatch({
    type: ActionTypes.GET_WEEK,
    data: data, 
  });
  }).catch(function(err){
    // Handle the error
  })
}
```

And this is how that API call looks using superagent-promise:

```
getWeek: function() {
  return superagent
      .get( url )
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .query({
        // Query
      })
      .end()
      .then(function(res) {
        var week = res.body;
        if ( !week ) {
          return Promise.reject( new Error("Error") );
        } else {
          return week;
        }
      });
```

},

This way you are dispatching an action only after getting back from API call. Once the store get the action you can call your `updateSortWeek()` function.